# How to use JWT to store data in NextAuth

Tags: json, jwt, next.js, next-auth

I return the following JSON after confirming credentials:

```
{username: 'foo', name: 'bar', type: 123}
```

However, NextAuth does not allow me to store all the fields due to model limitations, so what it returns in JWT to client is:

```
{name: 'bar', email: null, image: null}
```

My **[...nextauth].js** setup is very basic:

```
providers: [
    Providers.Credentials({
        async authorize(credentials) {
            const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/user', {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'credentials': JSON.stringify(credentials)
                }
            })
            const user = await res.json()
            
            if (user && !user.message) {
                return user
            } else {
                return null
            }
        }
    })
],
```

The only solution I came up with is to fake email field with JSON string in which I can store everything I need:

```
{name: 'bar', email: "{username: 'foo', type: 123}", image: null}
```

How can I do it properly? I tried looking into custom models (https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/typeorm-custom-models), but it seems to be only about databases, which is not my case since I use JWT for session storage.
Also what drawbacks I can encounter if I continue with my solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will need to persist the additional info through callbacks, at first through [JWT's callback](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#jwt-callback) and then [Session's callback](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#session-callback):

```
  callbacks: {
    async jwt(token, user, account, profile, isNewUser) {
      // Since you are using Credentials' provider, the data you're persisting 
      // _should_ reside in the user here (as far as can I see, since I've just tested it out).
      // This gets called whenever a JSON Web Token is created (once) or updated
      if (user?.type) {
        token.status = user.type
      }
      if (user?.username) {
        token.username = user.username;
      }
      
      return token
    },
  
    async session(session, token) {
      session.type = token.type;
      session.username = token.username;
      
      return session
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's the optional chaining operator ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining ), you can just do a (user && user.type) if you prefer.

Comment: may I ask, If we were to update the jwt token after some changes to the user document, how would we do that?