# NextAuth.js is not saving or returning extra data in autorize

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I would like to return uuid with name and email, but I only can save name and email and uuid is discarted

"next-auth": "^4.18.10",
"next": "13.2.4",

In callback session it only returns email and name not uuid

I need the uuid to make a query in server side props

How can I add extra data to autorize return besides email and name

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';

export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        //@ts-ignore
        CredentialsProvider({
            type: 'credentials',
            credentials: {
                name: {
                    label: 'Name',
                    type: 'text',
                },
                email: {
                    label: 'email',
                    type: 'text',
                },
                uuid: {
                    label: 'uuid',
                    type: 'text',
                },
            },
            //@ts-ignore

            async authorize(credentials: any) {
                const { correo, password } = credentials as {
                    correo: string;
                    password: string;
                };
                console.log(credentials);
                return {
                    name: 'aaaa',
                    uuid: '123aa456789',
                    email: 'asfasf@dsad.com',
                };
            },
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        //@ts-ignore

        session: async ({ session, token, user }) => {
            if (session?.user) {
            }
            console.log('HAY');
            console.log(session.user);
            return {
                name: 'aaaa',
                uuid: '123aa456789',
                email: 'asfasf@dsad.com',
            };
        },
    },
    secret: '1323456789',
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt',
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 30 Days
    },
});
```

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75449694/13488990) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

To add extra data, such as the UUID, to the return object in the authorization process using NextAuth, you can make use of the `jwt` property in your NextAuth configuration. Here's an example of how you can modify your code to include the UUID:

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      // Provider configuration...
    }),
  ],
  
  // Add the `jwt` property
  jwt: {
    encode: async ({ secret, token, maxAge }) => {
      const encodedToken = // Encode the token with the extra data
        await yourTokenEncodingFunction(secret, token);  // Replace with your own token encoding logic
      
      return encodedToken;
    },
    decode: async ({ secret, token, maxAge }) => {
      const decodedToken = // Decode the token and extract the extra data
        await yourTokenDecodingFunction(secret, token);  // Replace with your own token decoding logic
      
      return decodedToken;
    },
  },
  
  // Rest of your NextAuth configuration...
});
```

By utilizing the `jwt` property, you can customize token encoding and decoding processes. In the `encode` function, you can encode the token with any additional data you require, including the UUID. And in the `decode` function, you can decode the token and extract the UUID along with other data.

Make sure you update `yourTokenEncodingFunction` and `yourTokenDecodingFunction` with your implementation logic that handles token encoding and decoding.

By including the UUID in the token using the `jwt` property, it will be available in the session callback and can be accessed in the `session.user` object along with the email and name.